# RESOLVED - First machine learning no module named 'tree'

Tags: python

I decided to get into machine learning and I started in Python to make getting into it a bit easier but after getting anaconda and writing this:

```
import sklearn 
import tree
features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 0], [170, 0]]
lables = [0, 0, 1, 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
print(clf.predict([[150, 0]]))
```

But the problem is when I run it in anaconda3 the error message it gives back is

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tree'

and I have no idea why.

**RESOLUTION**

In this situation, the following package should resolve the issue. There are a few 'tree' packages but this solution is mentioned in https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/7645.

```
pip install dm-tree
```

Comment: What do you expect `tree` to be?

Answer (score 4):

You need to import tree like this

```
from sklearn import tree
```

tree is a part of the scikit module, hence you need to import tree from sklearn.
Also try reading the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html). It'll help a lot.

Comment: Thanks! Sry Im pretty new to python and had no idea that was even a thing...

Answer (score -3):

You can also write it as:
`clf=sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()`

You cannot simply import sklearn first, then import tree. This is because tree is a part of 'sklearn'. Tree itself is not a module.

A little advice though, try to get comfortable with the basics, and then crack your head in Machine Learning. It will be easier for you write your scripts then. ;-)